# Cannot run KVM, Android studio failing

Tags: 13.04, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install KVM but getting following errors:

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: The important bit is "Your CPU does not support KVM extensions KVM acceleration can NOT be used", what type of CPU is it ? and can you enable KVM (may be called vitualization or some variation of that) in your bios ?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator is a virtual mobile device emulator that runs on your computer. this lets you test android applications without using a physical device.
To use the emulator, you create a set of AVD(Android Virtual Devices) config. In each config, you cans set different platform and various set of hardware options
Many CPUs provide extensions for running virtual machines (VMs) more efficiently. Taking advantage of these extensions with the Android emulator requires some additional configuration of your development system, but can significantly improve the execution speed.

Linux-based systems support virtual machine acceleration through the KVM software package.
So, follow this steps to install KVM.

Check is your CPU supports Hardware virtualiation, use this command.

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

if Output is 0, Its doesn't support.
if you get output >= 1, Its does.

Now check your bios setting and make sure that virtualiation is enabled in bios.

Check whether you are running a 64 bit or 32 bit processor(optional, but recommended)

```
uname -m
```

if you get output as x86_64 indicates you are running 64 bit, if you see i386, i486, i586 or i686 then its a 32 bit.

now install kvm,

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Once done, make sure you add your username to group libvirtd

```
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd

sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
```

after adding, you may need to relogin to become a effective user.

if you get stuck anywhere, let me know also you can follow the links below to get more details.

Links : [Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html),  [KVM/Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)
.

---

Original Post :
Follow this link,

[link]The same link for KVM/Installation.

hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the info, looks like my cp doesn't support virtualization its a old intel 32-bit core 2 duo procession .